# How do we reduce the array that It will only show the small and the largest value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have an array with associative key show below:-

**Updated**

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0:{id ="1", start_time: 32400, end_time: 46800}
 1:{id ="2", start_time: 50400, end_time: 72000}
```

See In this array there are two start times and two end times I just want to reduce this array like it will only show me that start time which is lowest and show bigger end time and join all the id which it use to compare and show me like as output mentioned below:-

```
(1) [{…}, {…}]
 0:{id ="1,2", start_time: 32400, end_time: 72000}
```

How will I will I reduce the array.

Comment: you'd use reduce rather than sort

Comment: yeah I edit it @JaromandaX :p

Comment: why? you asked, I gave you a hint, don't change your question, clearly you didn't know - also, traditionally, people try to write code before asking for code on stack overflow

Answer (score 2):

Use `reduce` instead, `sort` doesn't make any sense here:

```js
const arr = [
  {start_time: 32400, end_time: 46800},
  {start_time: 50400, end_time: 72000},
  {start_time: 88000, end_time: 99000}
];
const result = arr.reduce((a, { start_time, end_time }) => ({
  start_time: Math.min(a.start_time, start_time),
  end_time: Math.max(a.end_time, end_time),
}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: but the question asks *"How will I make the `reduce` function of this."* :p

Comment: @certainperformance I update my question can you please tell me about this??

Comment: Please read: [“What to do when someone answers” - Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal). Ask your full question *initially*, not after people answer and you decide it's not enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
var arr = [{start_time: 32400, end_time: 46800},{start_time: 50400, end_time: 72000}];

var map = arr.reduce((a,curr)=>{
    a.start_time = a.start_time && a.start_time < curr.start_time? a.start_time : curr.start_time;
    a.end_time = a.start_time && a.end_time > curr.end_time  ?  a.end_time : curr.end_time;
    return a;
},{});
console.log(map);
```